# how to handle a click event only on, the element which is not hold the any other events?

Tags: jquery

I need to make a show navigation click event to ipad apps, it means, wherever i click on the ipad, it should show the navigation. in case if the element contained the click event then, the event(containing event) has to trigger, and it should not call the navigation display..

simply i say, how can i find the element which contain the event or not, and direct accordingly, i don't have any idea about this...

i used the jQuery's `:not([a=href])` function, but some where, my "div" element itself containing the click events. finally there is a full page, the total page itself has a click event... in that case how can i handle this issue...

can any one help me with good idea? please..

Comment: Do you mean that there's a `click` event on the `body` and any `click` event on `anchor` or `div` element on the UI also triggers the `click` event of `body`?

Comment: `s/click/touch/g` when dealing with iPads.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

```
$("body").on("click touch", function(event) {
  alert(event.target.nodeName + " was clicked/touched");
});
```

Comment: can i do, function(e){ if(!e.target) shownavigation()}, is it correct way to do?

Comment: I doubt that would work; the click/touch event should always have a target.

Comment: any good idea to show the navigation, with avoiding functional element?